# Unity GameOject .SetActive(false) when clicked or touched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to detect if a `GameObject` is touched or clicked and deactivate it. I have followed a Youtube tutorial but cant get it to work.

I get the error `Cannot convert from UnityEngine.Ray to UnityEngine.Vector2`

I have the script attached to the object.

```
public class Hand : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit2D;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray, out hit2D)) {
                transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
When a click is detected you are disabling the object. Unity has a very handy way of dealing with this problem. Here is the code for it:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        this.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I have have tried it and get nothing though. Do I need a collider?

Comment: Yah you'll probably need a collider. I have not tried it yet but if this does not work comment back and I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

`Physics2D.Raycast` has no version with `Ray` parameters; and is not really intended to work with the Z axis, which a camera-to-world cast needs, either.

Use `OnMouseDown()` instead. If on the clicked object itself, as `transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);` indicates to be the case, no further action is needed.

If for an external object, you can get the mouse world position with `var worldMousePoint 
 = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenPointWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`, and then check for overlap on a target Collider2D with `worldMousePoint == targetCollider2D.ClosestPoint(worldMousePoint)`.